# operating systems - TLBs

Tags: operating-system, tlb

I'm trying to get my head round this (okay, tbh cramming a night before the exams :) but i can't figure out (nor find a good high level overview on the net) of this:

'page table entries can be mapped to more than one TLB entry.. if for example every page table entry is mappped to two TLB entries, this is know as 2-way set associative TLB'

My question is, why would we want to map this more than once? surely we want to have the maximum number of possible entries represented in the TLB, and duplication would waste space right ? What am i missing?

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't mean you would load the same entry into two places into the table -- it means a particular entry can be loaded to *either* of two places in the table. The alternative where you can only map an entry to one place in the table is a direct mapped TLB.

The primary disadvantage of a direct-mapped TLB arises if you're copying from one part of memory to another, and (by whatever direct-mapping scheme the CPU uses) the translations for both have to be mapped to the same spot in the TLB. In this case, you end up re-loading the TLB entry every time, so the TLB is doing little or no good at all. By having a two-way set associative TLB, you can guarantee that any two entries can be in the TLB at the same time so (for example) a block move from point A to point B can't ruin your day -- but if you read from two areas, combine them, and write results to a third it could (if all three used translations that map map to the same set of TLB entries).

The shortcoming of having a multiway TLB (like any other multiway cache) is that you can't directly compute *which* position might hold a particular entry at a given time -- you basically search across the ways to find the right entry. For two-way, that's rarely a problem -- but four ways is typically about the useful limit; 8-way set associative (TLBs | caches) aren't common at all, partly because searching across 8 possible locations for the data starts to become excessive.

Over time, the number of ways it makes sense to use in a cache or tlb tends to rise though. The differential in speed between memory and processors continues to rise. The greater the differential, the more cycles the CPU can use and still produce a result within a single memory clock cycle (or a specified number of memory clock cycles, even if that's more than one).